# Stream File at REST webservice and start print job on Desktop application

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I´ve created a webservice for getting a file:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/print")
public class PictureWebservice {

    @GET
    @Path("/startPrint")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response getFile() {

        String path = "/mypath.JPG";
      File file = new File(path);
      return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
          .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" ) //optional
          .build();
    }
}
```

I will call from another PC (on which runs another Desktop application) the REST webservice because I need this file (or stream) for printing on this Desktop application.

Here my workflow:

1) Call webservice for getting file (an image) test.png

2) The PC on which runs the Desktop application get the file (maybe stream?)

3) The desktop application will start a print job in this PC

First of all:

1) How can I do this?

2) Should I store the file on my Desktop application PC physically? Because I don´t need the file only for prinint?

Can you help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

1. That depends on what language you choose to write the desktop application in.  I'll assume Java.

   1. Create a `HttpURLConnection` with a URL to the REST service,
   2. Get the input stream from the `HttpURLConnection`,
   3. Decode the data from the stream into a `BufferedImage` with `ImageIO.read()`, and use the Graphics2D and Print APIs to print it.
2. By "store physically", do you mean save it to disk?  Depending on what else you need to do with these images -- and in what time frame -- the answer should be fairly clear.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Do you have some code, please? Yes I mean save on disk. Is this necessary? Yes, I´m using JAVA

Comment: I have lots of code, but it's all in my head.  Others have taken the time to post theirs on the internet - please use the search function (or Google) to find it.